# Which "Processor family" to choose under "Processor type and features"?

Tags: linux, kernel, cpu, x86

I have recently compiled a minimal kernel for my **Intel(R) Pentium(R) Dual  CPU  T3400  @ 2.16GHz**, and chose **CONFIG_MCORE2 (Core 2/newer Xeon)** under "Processor type and features > Processor family"

I don't know if this is related, but my laptop has **2GB** of RAM, and the resulting kernel, when compiled, limited my RAM to only **800MB**.

Searching google for my CPU doesn't bring anything useful!

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 15
model name  : Intel(R) Pentium(R) Dual  CPU  T3400  @ 2.16GHz
stepping    : 13
microcode   : 0xa3
cpu MHz     : 2166.000
cache size  : 1024 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 2
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fdiv_bug    : no
hlt_bug     : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 10
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm lahf_lm dtherm
bogomips    : 4322.39
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 15
model name  : Intel(R) Pentium(R) Dual  CPU  T3400  @ 2.16GHz
stepping    : 13
microcode   : 0xa3
cpu MHz     : 2166.000
cache size  : 1024 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 2
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 1
initial apicid  : 1
fdiv_bug    : no
hlt_bug     : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 10
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm lahf_lm dtherm
bogomips    : 4322.39
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look, your CPU family `cpu family  : 6`, which matches the description in `CONFIG_MCORE2`:

`Newer ones have 6 and older ones 15`

That's the right config to choose.

And your memory issue, as you disabled HIGHMEM, your kernel can only use 896M memory space.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have any ideas on the RAM issue? I also set CONFIG_NR_CPUS=2 and CONFIG_NOHIGHMEM=y.

Comment: Uh, I see I have made some confusion here. Seems that I need to set CONFIG_NOHIGHMEM to 4GB for a 2GB machine. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @TeresaeJunior you need to enable HIGHMEM, otherwise you can only see 768M memory

Comment: Are you building a 32 bit kernel?  Why?

Comment: @warl0ck: It seems to me that the phrase "Newer ones have 6 and older ones 15" refers to Xeon CPUs only. The OP has a Pentium processor instead. Since Pentium is neither Xeon nor Core 2, I think `CONFIG_MCORE2` is not the correct option to enable. Unfortunately I don't know which is the correct one.